# How to remove error when declaring an array of a class in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, class

Basically, I'm making a reversi app for Android, and I am currently at the point of setting up the game board. The way I am intending to do this is to create a 2D array of the position class. Each position is represented by an imageview that is used as a button which represents a board position. Here is a snippet of the code that contains the error:

```
setupBoard(board);
....
public void setupBoard(Position board[][]) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
            Log.d("Error","Error a");
            board[x][y] = new Position(getApplicationContext());
            Log.d("Error","Error b");
            board[x][y].isPositionEmpty = true;

        }
    }
}
```

In the position class:

```
public class Position {

Context myContext;
public Position(Context context) {
    Log.d("Error","Error c");
    myContext = context;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}


public boolean isPositionEmpty = true;
public int positionID;


public  ImageView button = new ImageView(myContext);
```

}

The program gets to error a, but no further. The error in LogCat is:
    java.lang.NullPointerException

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Exception: 
    02-20 16:52:20.820: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-20 16:52:20.820: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{trinity.hazard.reversi/trinity.hazard.reversi.SinglePlayerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-20 16:52:20.820: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
    02-20 16:52:20.820: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-20 16:52:20.820: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-20 16:52:20.820: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-20 16:52:20.820: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-20 16:52:20.820: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-20 16:52:20.820: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-20 16:52:20.820: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 16:52:20.820: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-20 16:52:20.820: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-20 16:52:20.820: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-20 16:52:20.820: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-20 16:52:20.820: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-20 16:52:20.820: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:100)
02-20 16:52:20.820: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at trinity.hazard.reversi.SinglePlayerActivity.(SinglePlayerActivity.java:24)
02-20 16:52:20.820: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-20 16:52:20.820: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
02-20 16:52:20.820: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
02-20 16:52:20.820: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
02-20 16:52:20.820: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     ... 11 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Position class, try moving the line where you create the ImageView into the constructor, but AFTER initializing myContext.

Comment: Oh duh, you're right. This is the problem. Good catch! However, I would suggest removing the reference to the Context from Position and just initialize the ImageView with it. The fewer the references to a Context, the better.

Comment: m1ntf4n: It wont let me, the singlePlayerActivity isnt able to see the buttons. thanks for the help anyway

Comment: Glad I could help. Always be aware that any initialization you do outside the constructor will actually be copied to the beginning of each constructor (but after a super()call, if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: dmon: Ive tried this before, but I couldnt find a valid context to use when creating the imageView

Comment: Right, you still need to pass it in, but you don't need the reference in the Position class. Also, why are you using the Application Context? You should be using the activity (e.g. `new Position(this)`).

Comment: Sorry if I'm a bit confused, but... Did this solve your problem? Or are you still getting an exception?

Comment: Dmon1 I tried using this as a context, but I still had the same problem

Comment: Please post the entire exception. Where exactly do you define the method setupBoard()? In an activity?

Comment: M1ntf4n: here are the first few lines of code:  ' public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstantState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstantState);
  setContentView(R.layout.singleplayer);
  
  Player humanPlayer = new Player();
  
  final Position[][] board = new Position[8][8];
  
  Log.d("random Int",String.valueOf(whoPlaysFirst));
  
  playerName=getPlayerName(humanPlayer);
  Piece piece = new Piece();
  
  if(whoPlaysFirst == 1){
   playerTurn = true;
  } else if(whoPlaysFirst == 0){
   playerTurn = false;
  }
  
  
  setupBoard(board);'

Comment: I'm still missing the exception LogCat shows you. You may also edit your question and add the code rather there instead of posting it in a comment

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7967/discussion-between-m1ntf4n-and-hazard1994)